# hosting a room full of our youth on laptops networked together

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, minecraft

we would like to host a room full of laptops/computers all hooked for our youth group to play minecraft together on one hosted server - we have a service for the minecraft hosted server but we are wondering what we will need to have about 15-20 laptops hooked up to internet in one room all playing together. im not sure if its because i dont know the right lingo to ask for my answer but so far have not been able to come up with nay real knowledge that helps. any info/tips would be appreciated!
thank you!

Comment: Some kind of Switch. Please note that Hardware Recommendations are off -topic.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have an internet connection and a router with some type of built in switch, you would need to get an additional switch with enough ports on it for each person connected + 1 (to connect the switch to the router). An unmanaged switch will not need any configuration and should be plug and play.

If your router has Wi-Fi and all of the devices you want to use (laptops and desktops) also have Wi-Fi then you can just connect them as normal.

If your router does not have a built in switch, then you would need to get a router that has at least one LAN port on it to connect the switch too.

You can also mix and match, if only some of the devices have Wi-Fi capabilities, which could allow you to possibly get a switch with fewer connections.

You Should be aware that Wi-Fi can have performance impacts from a lot of factors, one of which is the amount of connected clients. This may result in some people having a more stable or lower latency connection than others.

Check out this wiki page for more information on network switches.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch

Comment: With 20 dynamic users, an extremely good wifi router will be required with multiple antennas.

Comment: @harrymc True, I did point out that Wi-Fi can be effected by a lot of things in my answer. I edited my answer to make that more clear.